# How to I pass random numbers for an array where I want the arrays within the array to remain in sequential order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

questions is the main array calling q1-q40 randomly. There is a different radio buttons for each answer how do I sort this?

function next()
    {

```
var randNo = Math.round(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40) -1);

document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = questions[0][0]; 
document.getElementById("rad1").innerHTML = questions[0][1];
document.getElementById("rad2").innerHTML = questions[0][2];
document.getElementById("rad3").innerHTML = questions[0][3];
document.getElementById("rad4").innerHTML = questions[0][4];
document.getElementById("image").src = images[randNo];
```

Comment: Could you show an example output? I'm not sure what you're looking to have happen here. What is currently happening and what is the problem with that output? You're interacting with the DOM but asking about arrays, so I'm especially confused. Is that part part of the question?

Comment: A few other issues, `parseInt(1)` returns `1`, you're missing a closing bracket, there's inconsistent spacing around the variables, you're using undefined variables.

Comment: I've fixed the code and the array works now.  what I was needing help with was I am using 1 array to store 1 question and 4 fixed answers and Im using a radio button for selection. I wanting to know how to have each question go for 10 times before returning to start screen, my radio buttons have no function.